# The emissivity of snow

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, ndvi

I try to use the NDVI Based Emissivity Method to calculate the LSE. But the function almost applied over surfaces composed by soil and vegetation. Over surfaces like water, ice, or snow did not describe carefully. Can anyone tell me how to calculate the emissivity of snow and water in Landsat images?